# Error in a r function based on a dataset information

Tags: r, dataframe, function, dplyr

I have this dataset:

```
df <- data.frame( raca = c("Nel","Nel","Nel", "Nel","Angus","Angus","Angus","Angus"),
                  marmo = c(350, 320, 330, 400, 800, 820, 450, NA))
```

and I would like to do the descriptive statistics. I used this code:

```
df %>%
  group_by(raca) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(across(1,~data.frame(Média =round(mean(.,na.rm=TRUE,digits=2),digits = 2),
                                                    N = length(.),
                                                    DP = round(sd(.,na.rm=TRUE),digits = 2),
                                                    Min = min(.,na.rm=TRUE),
                                                    Max = max(.,na.rm=TRUE),
                                                    `Coef Variação` = round(sd(., na.rm=TRUE)/mean(.,na.rm=TRUE)*100,digits=2)))) %>%
  pivot_longer(-raca) %>% arrange(name,raca)
```

and worked well. But I would like to a function, and I tried this code:

```
desc_function <- function(a,b, c)   { a %>%
    group_by(a[,b]) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(across(a[,c],~data.frame(Média =round(mean(.,na.rm=TRUE,digits=2),digits = 2),
                                              N = length(.),
                                              DP = round(sd(.,na.rm=TRUE),digits = 2),
                                              Min = min(.,na.rm=TRUE),
                                              Max = max(.,na.rm=TRUE),
                                              `Coef Variação` = round(sd(., na.rm=TRUE)/mean(.,na.rm=TRUE)*100,digits=2)))) %>%
    pivot_longer(a[,b]) %>% arrange(name,a[,b])}


desc_function(df, "raca", "marmo")
```

But this error happened:

```
 Error: Problem with summarise() input ..1.
i ..1 = across(...).
x Selections can't have missing values.
i The error occurred in group 1: a[, b] = "Angus".
Run rlang::last_error() to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: You may want to search for "Programming with Dplyr" and read the docs which is well explained.

Comment: @shafee So, for any question your answer will do. Remember, not everyone here is an expert, and what is easy for you may be difficult for me.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt mean to say its easy or anything,  I have just tried to refer to you a proper direction

Comment: `Dplyr`, works well, my problem is use `Dplyr`  with a `function`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with shafee that reading how to program with `dplyr` is slightly differently.

Here's how you would do it (adapting your code directly)

```
desc_function <- function(a,b, c)   { a %>%
    group_by(.data[[b]]) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(across(.data[[c]],~data.frame(Média =round(mean(.,na.rm=TRUE,digits=2),digits = 2),
                                              N = length(.),
                                              DP = round(sd(.,na.rm=TRUE),digits = 2),
                                              Min = min(.,na.rm=TRUE),
                                              Max = max(.,na.rm=TRUE),
                                              `Coef Variação` = round(sd(., na.rm=TRUE)/mean(.,na.rm=TRUE)*100,digits=2)))) %>%
    pivot_longer(-.data[[b]]) %>% arrange(name,.data[[b]])}


desc_function(df, "raca", "marmo")
```

Note the use of `.data[[b]]` to call string variables from the function

Alternatively pass the variables not enclosed in strings like so

```
desc_function <- function(a,b, c)   { a %>%
    group_by({{b}}) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(across({{c}},~data.frame(Média =round(mean(.,na.rm=TRUE,digits=2),digits = 2),
                                              N = length(.),
                                              DP = round(sd(.,na.rm=TRUE),digits = 2),
                                              Min = min(.,na.rm=TRUE),
                                              Max = max(.,na.rm=TRUE),
                                              `Coef Variação` = round(sd(., na.rm=TRUE)/mean(.,na.rm=TRUE)*100,digits=2)))) %>%
    pivot_longer(-{{b}}) %>% arrange(name,{{b}})}


desc_function(df, raca, marmo)
```

This time using `{{b}}` etc.

All, as mentioned, documented in https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem, for which you are getting an error, is that the code

```
function(df, "raca", "marmo")
```

Is used to define a function, not call a function. You should instead use the defined name of your function, like this:

```
desc_function(df, "raca", "marmo")
```

Comment: my bad, when i was writing this question i did it wrong. But I already corrected

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to passing variables as character for dynamic input using `!!sym(x)`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame( raca = c("Nel","Nel","Nel", "Nel","Angus","Angus","Angus","Angus"),
                  marmo = c(350, 320, 330, 400, 800, 820, 450, NA))


desc_function <- function(a, b, c)   { 
  a %>%
    group_by(!!sym(b)) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(across(matches(c), ~data.frame(Média =round(mean(.,na.rm=TRUE,digits=2),digits = 2),
                                           N = length(.),
                                           DP = round(sd(.,na.rm=TRUE),digits = 2),
                                           Min = min(.,na.rm=TRUE),
                                           Max = max(.,na.rm=TRUE),
                                           `Coef Variação` = round(sd(., na.rm=TRUE)/mean(.,na.rm=TRUE)*100,digits=2)))) %>%
    pivot_longer(!!sym(c)) %>% arrange(name, !!sym(b))
}

desc_function(df, "raca", "marmo")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   raca  name  value$Média    $N   $DP  $Min  $Max $Coef.Variação
#>   <chr> <chr>       <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>          <dbl>
#> 1 Angus marmo         690     4 208.    450   820           30.2
#> 2 Nel   marmo         350     4  35.6   320   400           10.2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

For further information you can reference to this e-book written by Hadley - https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write a function that contains `tidyverse` verbs (i.e. function), usual approach of function writing will not work, beacause these tidy functions follows `NSE` (non standard evaluation) approach. The easiest workaround is to use curly-curly `{{}}` from rlang package. Simply wrap the function arguments that you will use as columns in dplyr functions with curly-curly. So in your case the function would be,

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(rlang)

df <- data.frame(
    raca = c("Nel", "Nel", "Nel", "Nel", "Angus", "Angus", "Angus", "Angus"),
    marmo = c(350, 320, 330, 400, 800, 820, 450, NA)
)

df %>%
    group_by(raca) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(across(1, ~ data.frame(
        Média = round(mean(., na.rm = TRUE, digits = 2), digits = 2),
        N = length(.),
        DP = round(sd(., na.rm = TRUE), digits = 2),
        Min = min(., na.rm = TRUE),
        Max = max(., na.rm = TRUE),
        `Coef Variação` = round(sd(., na.rm = TRUE) / mean(., na.rm = TRUE) * 100, digits = 2)
    ))) %>%
    pivot_longer(-raca) %>%
    arrange(name, raca)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   raca  name  value$Média    $N   $DP  $Min  $Max $Coef.Variação
#>   <chr> <chr>       <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>          <dbl>
#> 1 Angus marmo         690     4 208.    450   820           30.2
#> 2 Nel   marmo         350     4  35.6   320   400           10.2


desc_function <- function(dat, grp_var, var = NULL) {
    df %>%
        group_by({{ grp_var }}) %>%
        dplyr::summarise(across(1, ~ data.frame(
            Média = round(mean(., na.rm = TRUE, digits = 2), digits = 2),
            N = length(.),
            DP = round(sd(., na.rm = TRUE), digits = 2),
            Min = min(., na.rm = TRUE),
            Max = max(., na.rm = TRUE),
            `Coef Variação` = round(sd(., na.rm = TRUE) / mean(., na.rm = TRUE) * 100, digits = 2)
        ))) %>%
        pivot_longer(-{{ grp_var }}) %>%
        arrange(name, {{ grp_var }})
}


desc_function(df, grp_var = raca)

#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   raca  name  value$Média    $N   $DP  $Min  $Max $Coef.Variação
#>   <chr> <chr>       <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>          <dbl>
#> 1 Angus marmo         690     4 208.    450   820           30.2
#> 2 Nel   marmo         350     4  35.6   320   400           10.2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: To get more idea why function works and why your approach doesn't work, I would really encourage you to read 4 chapters [chapter 17 to chapter 20] from [this book](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/metaprogramming.html) if want to understand in detail. And also see [programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)